# Where does $\nabla^R (f)$ belong to?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I am reading a paper [DRINFELD DOUBLE OF GLn AND GENERALIZED CLUSTER STRUCTURES](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.05705.pdf). I have a question about $\nabla^R f$ in Section 2 of page 7.

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra. Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ be a non-degenerate bilinear form on $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $f \in C^{\infty}(G)$. $\nabla^R f$ is defined as follows
\begin{align}
\langle \nabla^R f(X), \xi \rangle = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} f(Xe^{t \xi}),
\end{align}
where $X \in G, \xi \in \mathfrak{g}$. I think that $\nabla^R f(X)$ is in $\mathfrak{g}$. Is this correct? Where does $\nabla^R f$ belong to? Thank you very much.

Comment: The notation  is very unfortunate, since $\nabla$ in differential geometry usually denotes the covariant derivative. This $\nabla^R(f)$ is a differential 1-form on $G$. The quantity $\nabla^Rf(X)$ is not in ${\mathfrak g}$ but in its dual,  ${\mathfrak g}^*$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen, thank you very much. Is $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ the Killing form on $\mathfrak{g}$? If $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the Killing form on $\mathfrak{g}$, then $\langle \eta, \xi \rangle = tr(ad(\eta)ad(\xi))$, $\eta, \xi \in \mathfrak{g}$. How to define $\langle f, \xi \rangle$, $f \in \mathfrak{g}^*$, $\xi \in \mathfrak{g}$? It is said that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is a non-degenerate bilinear form on $\mathfrak{g}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $X\in G$. Then the mapping $\alpha : \mathfrak g \to \mathbb R$, 
$$ \xi  \mapsto \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}f(Xe^{t\xi})$$
is linear and thus $\alpha$ is an element in $\mathfrak g^*$.

Now you are given a bilinear form $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ on $\mathfrak g$. So you can define $A: \mathfrak g \to \mathfrak g^*$ by

$$ A(\xi) (\psi) = \langle \xi, \psi\rangle.$$

That the bilinear form is non-degenerate means that $A$ is invertible. Thus $\nabla^R f(X)$ is just $A^{-1}\alpha$. This is true for all $X\in G$, so you can think of $\nabla^R f$ as a map $\nabla^R f : G\to \mathfrak g$.